# Where is the "history" file in emacs?

Tags: emacs

Whenever I close emacs I get `"End of file during parsing" while saving the history.` , but I do not know where that history file is for me to fix. Someone has an idea, I know that **M-p** is back in history, **M-n** for next, and how do I delete the history? I did not find anything in the documentation about.

I found here about:

https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MinibufferHistory

but it does not tell me where to find the history file, where it is saved, or how to delete the history.

Comment: What do you mean by *"file history"* here? Closing Emacs does not save any minibuffer history (by default). Do you see the same problem if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not then bisect your init file to find the problem. That message doesn't seem to be from `savehist.el` or `recentf.el`. You can also try grepping the code (e.g. libraries you use) for that `while saving the history` string. I grepped the standard Lisp files for it but didn't find it there - probably some of your code or a library you're using. Try bisecting your init file.

Comment: Sounds like `flycheck` is trying to check the history file from `slime-repl` or `idris-repl`. Disable your slime/idris stuff in your Emacs init file, and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: @Drew I searched for "while saving the history" with grep, and found `./all/emacsd/elpa/slime-20180701.1344/contrib/slime-repl.el:   "%S while saving the history. Continue? "))`, I discovered that it was slime -repl that it was causing, the file it saved in "~/.slime-history.eld", delete it, it was empty, and added again, and now stopped receiving the error.

Comment: hehe good timing!

Comment: Bravo. Please consider providing your "history" of debugging this, and the conclusion, as an answer. You can accept your own answer. That can help other readers. Keep in mind that comments can be deleted at any time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I searched for "while saving the history" with `grep -R "while saving the history" /home/me/portacle/*`, and found:

```
 ./all/emacsd/elpa/slime-20180701.1344/contrib/slime-repl.el: "%S while saving the history. Continue? "))
```

I discovered that it was slime-repl that it was causing, the file it saved in `~/.slime-history.eld`.

I deleted the file(it was empty) and restarted the slime, so it re-created the file for me, and stopped causing the error.